# select ng-model ng-options doesn't work

Tags: angular, select, drop-down-menu, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Could you help me with my problem? I relly don't understand why it doesn't work.

I'd like to dynamically generate select from Level[] from database

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

**dictionary-item.component.html:**

```
<div class="pull-right level">
    <select id="levelSelect" ng-model="levelModel" ng-options="level as level.level for level in levels" (click)="stopPropagation($event)">
    </select>
  </div>
```

**dictionary-item.component.ts:**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dictionary-item',
      templateUrl: './dictionary-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dictionary-item.component.css']
    })
    export class DictionaryItemComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() dictionaryItem: DictionaryItem;
      levels: Level[] = [];

      constructor(private dictionaryService: DictionaryService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.levels = this.dictionaryService.getLevels();
        console.log(this.levels);
/*
from Chrome console:
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, level: 1}
1
:
{id: 2, level: 2}
2
:
{id: 3, level: 3}
3
:
{id: 4, level: 4}
4
:
{id: 5, level: 5}
length
:
5
__proto__
:
Array(0)
*/
      }
    }
```

this.dictionaryService.getLevels() returns Level[]:

where Level:

```
export class Level {
    public id: number;
    public level: number;

    constructor(id: number, level: number) { }
}
```

Why Angular generates a blank select list on the page? Without any values?

I've even tried to set in component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.levels = [new Level(1,1), new Level(2,2), new Level(3,3)];
  }
```

but without any generation of  on the website. Nothing.

Thank you in advance!
Mateusz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're not using angularJS.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="levelModel" (click)="stopPropagation($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let level of levels" [value]="level">{{ level }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: AAaaaaaaaaaa, no questions. It was very strange to me...I was surprised what is this... But no information that it's not angularjs... Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, if your issue is resolved be sure to mark it as so.